# submit() function is not working when I call window.close() method

Tags: javascript, spring

I opened popup, then I call submit() function.
If there's no window.close() function in this code, submit() could be called.
But after I added window.close() function, submit() is not working. cannot call controller(?)
plz help for this. Thanks

```js
     var frm = document.getElementById("modifyForm");
     frm.action = G_CONTEXT_PATH + "/web/bndtAdmin/bndtUsermodify.do?bndtUserSeq=" + bndtUserSeq;
     frm.method = "POST";
     frm.submit();
     window.close();
```

Comment: So you have an element named submit in the form....

Comment: When you submit the form return a bare html page with just a script tag and put `window.close()` in that script tag

Comment: how about changing `frm.submit()` to `await frm.submit()`?

Comment: @ericanthony - that would assume two things. 1) the function calling frm.submit  `async` and more importantly, 2) from.submit *returns a Promise*